# Unable to connect to the mongodb instance running in a docker container from outside

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

The following code snippet is a part of my "docker compose" file and as you see, the internal port of 27017 was mapped to 37017 to prevent colliding with the MongoDB instance running on the host development machine:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 27017:37017
```

I use `Compass` when trying to connect to this mongo instance in docker and the following connection string, but Compass fails to connect to the database:

```
mongodb://host.docker.internal:37017
```

What is missing in this configuration keeping me from connecting to the mongodb in docker?

Comment: Your `ports:` are backwards: you're mapping port 27017 on the host (...which should have a conflict?) to port 37017 inside the container, but there's nothing listening there.  If the client is also in a container, you might attach it to the same network (or run it in the same Compose file) and use `mongodb://mongo:27017` to connect; this doesn't need or use `ports:` and won't conflict with a non-container MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The credit to this answer goes to David Maze. Switching the port numbers addressed the problem. The correct yaml looks like below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 37017:27017
```